# Retrieve all reactions from posts on my Facebook Business Page using PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using Facebook SDK for PHP v5 to retrieve information about my business page on Facebook. I need to retrieve reactions from my posts. Everything is working fine when my post has a few number of reactions. The results are send to a JSON file.

I'm using this code:

```
$limit = 5000;
$info_posts = "created_time,id,message,type,reactions.limit(" . $limit . "), comments.limit(" . $limit . "),sharedposts.limit(" . $limit . "){from}&method=GET";

$request = $fb->post('/' . $value['id'] . '?fields=' . $info_posts);
$graphNode = $request->getGraphNode();                  
fwrite($fp, json_encode(json_decode($post), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ));
```

When I execute using post id has more than 1000 reactions, the following error appear:

*Graph returned an error: Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request*

Any suggestions about how resolve this issue?

Comment: The error message already say it all: ***Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request***. Simply do as such for a possible resolution.

Comment: `They all have an upper boundary for the limit parameter of 100 posts. Specifying any higher limit will throw an error`. You can do nothing about that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/page/feed

Comment: Use a lower limit and use the next link

Comment: I'm retrieving reactions for only one post at time, so the boundary for 100 posts I understand does not apply. I've tried use next link but I can handle how configure that. Could you please send an example?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphEdge/5.0.0#pagination

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried GraphEdge but when run the following message appears: _Facebook SDK returned an error: Unable to convert response from Graph to a GraphEdge because the response does not look like a GraphEdge. Try using GraphNodeFactory::makeGraphNode() instead._ I'm using the following code: `$request = $fb->post('/' . $value['id'] . '?fields=' . $info_posts); $graphNode = $request->getGraphEdge(); var_dump($fb->next($graphNode));` Any idea?